# Java open one instance of JInternalFrame only

Tags: java

I am creating an inventory system using java but I am having problem in displaying only one JInternalFrame in my application. I put a condition that will validate if the JInternalFrame is already visible or not and it's working but the problem is that the first clicked doesn't display anything only after the succeeding clicks. Here is my code for calling the JInternalFrame class:

```
private Planning pFrame;

private void firstWindow()
{

    if(pFrame == null)
    {
        pFrame = new Planning();
        Dimension desktopSize = desktop.getSize();
        pFrame.setSize(desktopSize);
        pFrame.moveToFront();
        pFrame.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(pFrame);
        try{
            pFrame.setMaximum(true);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }

    if(pFrame.isVisible())
    {
        pFrame.setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        pFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. It displays no JInternalFrame.

Comment: Simply `pFrame.setMaximum(true);`. There are different JInternalPane constructors with some booleans. Set the background color (or border) of the JDesktop to see whether it is shown. Remove the if - always add.

Comment: What do you mean by "Remove the if - always add"? I tried your suggestion and it still creates new instances of JInternalFrame.

Comment: Planning is a JInternalFrame, firstWindow creates it. So firstWindow should be called once.  the Planning window maybe held in a field, so one can do: bringToFront, desktop.selectFrame(pFrame) or such.

Comment: I am a little confuse of your answer can you give a sample code of how to  - an alternative to the if statement that I made.

Comment: Better make a prototype application. Or search an example. You have a field `JInternalFrame pFrame;` For instance: on "opening it" look whether it is must be created `if (pFrame == null) { ... desktop.add(pFrame); }` else `pFrame.setVisible(true); pFrame.bringToFront();`

Comment: I followed your suggestion and my problem now is the desktop.add. It creates error when I will click and create another instance of the frame.

Comment: Sorry that I could not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After code and try for several hours I found my answer and this is my code that works:

```
private void firstWindow()
{
    if(pFrame == null)
    {
        pFrame = new Planning();
        Dimension desktopSize = desktop.getSize();
        pFrame.setSize(desktopSize);
        desktop.add(pFrame);
        pFrame.setVisible(true);
        pFrame.moveToFront();
        try{
            pFrame.setMaximum(true);
            pFrame.setSelected(true);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    else if(!pFrame.isVisible())
    {
        pFrame.setVisible(true);
        pFrame.moveToFront();
    }


    if(iFrame.isVisible())
    {
        desktop.remove(iFrame);
        iFrame = null;
    }
}

private void secondWindow()
{
    if(iFrame == null)
    {
        iFrame = new Inventory();
        Dimension desktopSize = desktop.getSize();
        iFrame.setSize(desktopSize);
        desktop.add(iFrame);
        iFrame.setVisible(true);
        iFrame.moveToFront();

        try{
            iFrame.setMaximum(true);
            iFrame.setSelected(true);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    else if(!iFrame.isVisible())
    {
        iFrame.setVisible(true);
        iFrame.moveToFront();
    }

    if(pFrame.isVisible())
    {
        desktop.remove(pFrame);
        pFrame = null;
    }
}
```

Note: I also found a way to close the previous frame when you open other frame class..

And in my internal frame I put this code to make its visibility to false if user clicks the close button.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(this.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Thanks to the people who helped...